# Unresolved external symbol while not actually using the function

Tags: c++-cli

Given the following C++/CLI program:

```
#pragma managed(push, off)

class FooBar
{
    FooBar(const FooBar& that) { *this = that; }
    const FooBar& operator =(const FooBar& that);
};

#pragma managed(pop)

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the following linker output:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "private: class FooBar const & __thiscall FooBar::operator=(class FooBar const &)" (??4FooBar@@AAEABV0@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "private: __thiscall FooBar::FooBar(class FooBar const &)" (??0FooBar@@AAE@ABV0@@Z)   ConsoleApplication1 C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj 1

But the following C++ program does not:

```
class FooBar
{
    FooBar(const FooBar& that) { *this = that; }
    const FooBar& operator =(const FooBar& that);
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The reason I need this to work is because I'm including a header file which is beyond my control that does this. Although I never need to use the copy constructor or the assignment operator.

Compiled using v142 platform toolset.

Comment: You do use operator=() in this program, the constructor needs it.  So it boils down to how efficiently the linker can remove dead code.  It has an easier time with native C++, /clr built code can't be eliminated the same way because the class is referenced in the assembly metadata.  Why this matters is pretty murky, it just never makes much sense to declare a function but not implement it.

Comment: @HansPassant I see. Well the operator is implemented but not exported to the DLL I link against. Is there any way to circumvent this. Again, I cannot change any source code in the header.

Comment: I should have smelled a rat I suppose.  Pick up the telephone, get it fixed.

Comment: @HansPassant I figuratively picked up the phone and had it fixed. It's really a pain in the butt that somehow the C++/CLI linker handles this differently

Comment: I figuratively answered it.